# Control printer head

Tags: linux, printing, hardware, drivers

I have an old HP Deskjet printer and my question is **how to control printer head XY**? It is important to make it *without additional microcontrolers*. Do I need to write custom printer driver on linux or use some printer language?
The main problem is that the printer won't print without paper. 
I'd like to be able to print PCB or use printer hardware as a plotter or CNC (XY controler in general). Is there any articles or books to start with?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the precise printer model but most likely this printer is either PCL or PostScript printer and this means that it uses higher level of abstraction in communication with the computer. The PCL (lower level) or postscript (higher level) languages are designed to tell printer what kind of *picture* you want, not the way how to draw this picture, and thus the information sent to printer contain no details on how to move printer head. Thus, most likely, you can do very little without modifying printer hardware.

Given this, you may try to invent some clever hack in how to use PCL language to make printer do what you want. Here is the places where you may start: look into /usr/lib/cups/backend/ and find the code that communicates directly with your printer interface (most likely it will be usb). Check the cups drivers to see the command line parameters for this interface. You can use this interface to send PCL language commands directly to printer. Now try to read some PCL language reference guide and find out how to force printer to do what you want. Most likely direct interface to hardware will be much simpler.

Comment: My Friend, will you please look at my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61994499/how-do-i-write-plotter-or-printers-driver. I would like to write the driver of a plotter. It has 8051's family micro controller which will control the X,Y,Z movement, which X,Y are coordinate while Z-axis is to lift the marking pen. Will you please help me how to start? Where to go to start to make the driver? The most important, how to make it available in the printer list in AutoCAD. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: First of all, I don't know much about writing drivers for Windows (and I prefer to never  touch this system). Secondly, I don't think, that plotter is the same kind of device as printer (even for Windows). Usually plotters communicate either in G-code over UART/RS-232/USB or are driven directly via LPT port. On Linux, it is responsibility of the user-space software to communicate with plotter.